# Geometric Series Formula Contradiction

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have had an issue with a certain contradiction I found in the formula for an infinite geometric series. I am sure I have made a mistake and that the logic is fine, but I can't figure out what I have done wrong, any and all help is appreciated. Here is my confusion:

Geomteric Series Formula:
$\sum^{p}_{k=0} ar^k = a(\frac{1-r^{p+1}}{1-r}) $

If we use this formula we can derive a formula for the convergence of the series below.

$\sum^{\infty}_{k=0} ar^{k+1} = \text{lim}_{p\to\infty} a(\frac{1-r^{p+2}}{1-r}) = \frac{a}{1-r} (1-\text{lim}_{x\to\infty} r^{p+2}) $

Assuming $-1 < r < 1$, the limit will approach $0$ and the whole expression can be evaluated as $\frac{a}{1-r}$

If we factor out r from the start, it would seem we can find a different formula which includes r as a factor.

$r\sum^{\infty}_{k=0} ar^k = r\cdot \text{lim}_{p\to\infty} a(\frac{1-r^{p+1}}{1-r}) = \frac{ar}{1-r}(1 - \text{lim}_{p\to\infty} r^{p+1})   $

This is because the limit still approaches $0$, so somehow $\frac{ar}{1-r} =\frac{a}{1-r} $. This of course is not true when you try using numbers instead of abstract variables, and you could factor as many $r$'s or $\frac{1}{r}$'s as we want. Thank you for reading, sorry if my mistake is obvious or conspicuous, I just can't seem to find whats wrong with my logic. Thank you for any and all help.

Answer (score 1):

The first expression is incorrect.  $\sum\limits_{k=0}^p ar^{k+1}=a\frac{1-r^{k+2}}{1-r}-a$.  Note the series first term is $ar$ not $a$.

Answer (score 0):

> If we use this formula we can derive a formula for the convergence of the series below.
> $\sum^{\infty}_{k=0} ar^{k+1} = \text{lim}_{p\to\infty} a(\frac{1-r^{p+2}}{1-r}) = \frac{a}{1-r} (1-\text{lim}_{x\to\infty} r^{p+2}) $

This formula is wrong.

First of all, your own analysis indicates that this formula causes a contradiction.

Beyond that, to understand why your formula is wrong, you have to understand the derivation of the original formula.

$\sum_{k=0}^n r^k = \frac{1 - r^{n+1}}{1-r}.$

So, when $\sum_{k=0}^n r^k$ is **estimated** as $\frac{1}{1-r}$, there is an **error term** of $E = \frac{-r^{n+1}}{1-r}.$

Assume $|r| < 1.$

Then, as $n \to \infty$, the error term, $E$, goes to $0$.

Consider the alternate summation:

$\sum_{k=0}^n r^{k+1} = \frac{r - r^{n+2}}{1-r}$.

When this summation is estimated as $\frac{r}{1-r}$, you have the error term $F = \frac{-r^{n+2}}{1-r}.$

So, if (again), $|r| < 1$,

then as $n \to \infty, F \to 0.$